# ¿Cómo se toca solo una sección de un arreglo de caracteres en java?

Tags: java, array

Digamos que tengo un `string` que es `"hola"`.

Si necesito solo imprimir el `"ola"` ¿Qué debo hacer sin tener que eliminar la `h`?

Ya intente con metodos parecidos a los de Python como el clásico :

```
print(palabra[1:2])
```

Pero no sirve.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio sade!, considera revisar [ask] y considera agregar lo que has realizado. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Una manera sencilla de hacerlo es con el método `substring()`. Seleccionas que empiece desde el carácter siguiente al primero de la palabra en cuestión.

**Ejemplo:**

```
String palabra = "hola";

System.out.println(palabra.substring(1,palabra.length()));
```

Resultado : `ola`

Utilizamos el método `length()` para calcular la longitud de la palabra que queramos.

Para hacerlo con los elementos de un array, basta con recorrerlo con un bucle.

```
String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};


 for(String arr : fruits){
     System.out.println(arr.substring(1,arr.length()));
 }
```

**Output:**

```
pple
anana
range
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de realizar esto

Una opción es convertir la cadena de caracteres a un arreglo de caracteres y extraer todas las letras a excepción de la primera letra (indice 0):

```
String palabra = "hola";
char[] palabraCaracteres = palabra.toCharArray();
//Obtiene texto a partir de la segunda letra.
System.out.println(new String((Arrays.copyOfRange(palabraCaracteres, 1, palabraCaracteres.length))));
```

Salida:

```
ola
```

---

Otra opción se realizaría mediante el método `substring()` en el cual defines que obtenga todas las letras a excepción de la primera letra (indice 0)

```
String palabra = "hola";
//Obtiene texto a partir de la segunda letra.
palabra = palabra.substring(1, palabra.length());
System.out.println(palabra);
```

Salida:

```
ola
```